# Making Navbar Transparent and putting the Image Behind

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

I am making a website and I am using Bootstrap for this. I just want to make the navbar transparent and Put the image behind it.

My HTML code for Navbar is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOTL</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Join</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

And below this I have an Image tag:

```
<img class="first-wallpaper" src="Images/League First Page.jpg" alt="legaue-wallpaper">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. For setting the background color of your nav to transparent

   nav{
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   }
2. Your image should be behind the nav

   .first-wallpaper{
       z-index: -1;
   }